# Angular, foreach into subscribe

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to build an array from data result from subscribe.

For now i have this:

```js
const dataFormat = new IData();
this.api.getData()
.pipe(
map(response => response),
tap(data => console.log('data array', data)))
.subscribe(dataResult => {
dataResult.forEach(function (item) {
     dataFormat.title = item['title'];
     dataFormat.author = item['author'];
     dataFormat.date = item['date'];
     this.listData.push(dataFormat);
});

});
```

In `this.listData.push` i have this error: `Potentially invalid reference access to a class field via 'this.' of a nested function`

If I use `let self = this` with `self.listData.push(dataFormat);` my array only store the last item from foreach.

Comment: `this.listData = dataResult.map(...)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's a **scope error**, **forEach is also know for that kind of mistakes**.

You should use a normal for loop instead of the forEach loop.

```
.subscribe(dataResult => {
   for(let item of dataResult) {
       dataFormat.title = item['title'];
       dataFormat.author = item['author'];
       dataFormat.date = item['date'];
       this.listData.push(dataFormat);
   }
});
```

**or if you still wanna stick to forEach loop, pass an arrow function instead:**

```
.subscribe(dataResult => {
   dataResult.forEach(item => {
       dataFormat.title = item['title'];
       dataFormat.author = item['author'];
       dataFormat.date = item['date'];
       this.listData.push(dataFormat);
   });
});
```